# SQL command to filter the databases which are audit tables

Tags: sql-server

Running this to get the results of all databases with all tables

```
DECLARE @src NVARCHAR(MAX), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @sql = N'', @src = N' UNION ALL 
SELECT ''$d'' as ''database'', 
    s.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''schema'',
    t.name COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI as ''table'' ,
    ind.rows as record_count
  FROM [$d].sys.schemas AS s
  INNER JOIN [$d].sys.tables AS t ON s.[schema_id] = t.[schema_id]
  INNER JOIN [$d].sys.sysindexes AS ind ON t.[object_id] = ind.[id]
  where ind.indid < 2';

SELECT @sql = @sql + REPLACE(@src, '$d', name)
  FROM sys.databases
  WHERE database_id > 4
    AND [state] = 0
    AND HAS_DBACCESS(name) = 1;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 10, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10));

PRINT @sql;
--EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

but want to filter the databases like every audit database has `_audit` attached to it.

Also I want to get all the views and stored procedures and functions to it

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why do you not simply add the appropriate logic in the where clause? Something like `and [name] not like N'%audit'`.

Comment: And the last part is more unclear -> "get all the views and stored procedures ...".  But that should probably be a second question. Typically one post here should be limited to a single question. I suggest you also try searching the internet if you are simply trying to script out various objects within your database.

Comment: the above query is just returning me tables, i want the views, spx and functions too

Comment: you better put your coments as answer